# How can I archive a specific stream with OpenTok?

Tags: opentok

How can I archive a specific stream only (for example by using the stream ID) with OpenTok? I don't want to archive any other stream in the session. Can the OpenTok archiving feature used for it? In the *opentok.js* documentation I can only find information on how to archive the whole session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Unfortunately, you cannot choose to archive any one specific stream, you can only archive a session. However, you have the option of creating an [individual stream archive](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/#individual-stream-and-composed-archives) instead of a composed archive which will allow you to get the individual stream.

An individual stream archive is a ZIP container file with multiple individual media files for each stream, and a JSON metadata file for video synchronization. Please keep in mind that this format of archiving is not available for automatically archived sessions.

For more information, please take a look at the [OpenTok Archiving Guide](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/).

Comment: I've used individual archiving, but its not audible at all. I understand that we need to do some post processing to make the archives playable. I've used github.com/opentok/archiving-composer and still the video is not audible. Do I need to do any more processing using `ffmpeg`?